# Querying part of a string

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to query a column which contains string such as

```
595.1,N30.10
630.5,E10
```

I have tried separating the two values into different columns

```
split_part(code, ',', 1) AS code1, 
split_part(code, ',', 2) AS code2
```

But now I see that some of the rows have 3 (or could be more)

```
785.59, R57.1, R
```

I wonder if there is a way to specify and query only the first part of the string without having to split the string. In this case only look for enteries with 595.1,785.59 and ignore the rest.

```
SELECT distinct ON (id) id,time,year,code
FROM data
where code= ANY('{595.1,785.59}');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already the have logic you need, you only need to thread it together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, time, year, code
FROM data
WHERE split_part(code, ',', 1) = ANY('{595.1,785.59}');
```

This logic appears to be working in the demo below.

### Demo

Comment: Edited the question, hope I am being clear this time.

Answer (score 1):

To query on first part of code column you can do like below

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE split_part(code, ',', 1) = somevalue
```